# How to implement "Last Non Empty" measures with Apache Spark and Sparkube?

Tags: apache-spark, olap, olap-cube

We use a combination of Apache Spark and Sparkube to create online analysis environments on the fly. The data is prepared in Spark and exposed as a multidimensionnal cube with Sparkube. Sparkube automatically publishes simple aggregations (SUM, MIN, MAX, AVG, STD...) but how can we support the "Last Non empty" kind of aggregation?

Take for instance this dataset where the quantity of stock of various products is periodically recorded. The stock for 2018 should not be the sum of the stock records taken that year, but the latest one within that year.

```
Time,Product,Stock
2017-11-01, Oranges, 40000
2017-11-01, Apples, 120000
2017-12-01, Oranges, 42000
2017-12-01, Apples, 110000
2018-01-01, Oranges, 50000
2018-01-01, Apples, 100000
2018-02-01, Oranges, 48000
2018-02-01, Apples, 130000
2018-03-01, Oranges, 46000
2018-03-01, Apples, 120000
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that stock quantity records (or positions in general) don't aggregate over time. But quantity variations do. So what you can do is use Spark to compute stock quantity variations, that will sum consistently in a cube, and then from your OLAP frontend create a calculated measure that will (re)compute the actual stock for any location in the cube.

Load the dataset in Spark and compute the stock variation per product

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

var ds = spark.read
.format("csv")
.option("header","true")
.option("inferSchema","true")
.load("/path/to/stock.csv")

val ws = Window.partitionBy("Product").orderBy("Time")

val ds2 = ds
  .withColumn("PreviousStockTmp", lag(col("Stock"), 1).over(ws))
  .withColumn("PreviousStock", when($"PreviousStockTmp".isNull, 0).otherwise($"PreviousStockTmp"))
  .drop("PreviousStockTmp")
  .withColumn("StockVariation", col("Stock").minus(col("PreviousStock"))).orderBy("Time")
```

Add the usual 'year', 'month', 'day' etc... columns that will be useful for online analysis

```scala
val ds3 = ds2
  .withColumn("Year", year(col("Time")))
  .withColumn("Month", month(col("Time")))
  .withColumn("Day", dayofmonth(col("Time")))
```

Finally publish the dataset as a cube with Sparkube

```scala
import com.activeviam.sparkube._
new Sparkube().fromDataset(ds3).expose()
```

Now you can browse the cube in Excel, Tableau or ActiveUI, you can use the "StockVariation.SUM" measure in charts and pivot tables. In MDX you can create a calculated measure to compute the stock from the variations:

```
WITH
 Member [Measures].[Stock] AS (
  (
    [Measures].[Stock],
    [Year].CurrentMember.PrevMember
  ) + [Measures].[StockVariation.SUM]
) 
SELECT
  NON EMPTY Crossjoin(
    [Year].[Year].[Year].Members,
    {
      [Measures].[Stock]
    }
  ) ON COLUMNS,
  NON EMPTY [Product].[Product].[Product].Members ON ROWS
  FROM [_sparkube_1]
```

[image]